# How can I define an inequality in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to define in sympy an inequality `inecuacion = "19 < -25*x - 1 <= 37"` so that I can print the solution set on a graph. When I print with a single value, i.e. like this: `2*x-4 < 0`, it  can be evaluated, but when it is `19 < -25*x - 1 <= 37`, I get the error:

```
raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Fragment of my code:

```
  inecuacion = "19 < -25*x - 1 <= 37"
  ineq = parse_expr(inecuacion)
  interval = solveset(ineq, domain=S.Reals)

  plot_interval(title=latex(ineq, mode="inline"),  
                start=interval.start, end=interval.end, 
                start_open=interval.left_open, end_open=interval.right_open,
                x_axis=(-10, 10),
                color="#073065")
```

How can I make it so that sympy can interpret this kind of inequality `19 < -25*x - 1 <= 37`? Tanks very much. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
ineq = "20 < 3*x + 5 < 26"

parts = re.split(r"([<>]=?)", ineq)
eq1= "".join(parts[:3])
eq2 = "".join(parts[-3:])
print(eq1)
print(eq2)
```

As you can see, the trick is the regular expression `([<>]=?)` which means the following:

- The parentheses, we are going to create a capturing group. That will cause `re.split()` to not only return the resulting "chunks", but also return the "separators" between the chunks (which are the inequality signs of the inequalities).
- The brackets `[<>]` which can appear either `<` or `>`
- The equal with a question mark `=?` which can optionally appear with an equal sign (so that it admits `>=` and `<=` as a separator)

The result of `re.split()` is going to be a list with five chunks, as long as your input string has a pair of inequality comparers. The first chunk would be in this example the `"20 "`. The next chunk would be the first separator (`"<"` in the example) the next chunk would be " 3*x +5"`in this case. The next would be the second separator, again`"<"`in this example, and the fourth and last chunk would be`"26"`.

The following `.join()` joins the appropriate pieces together to form two expressions (inequalities). One with the first three pieces, another with the last three. The result on `eq1` and `eq2` is:

```html
20 < 3*x + 5
 3*x + 5 < 26
```

Once we have it separated in this way, we can use `sympy` to solve the two inequalities, for example like this:

```py
from sympy import solve, S
ineq = [S(eq) for eq in (eq1, eq2)]
intervals = solve(ineq, domain=S.Reals)
```

The solution found by sympy is an And operation between two intervals and it shows it like this:

```
(5 < x) & (x < 7)
```

If you want to reduce it to "a single interval" you could calculate the intersection of these two intervals with the interval `(-infinity, +infinity)`, for example like this:

```
from sympy import Interval, solveset

solution = Interval(float("-inf"), float("+inf"))
for interval in intervals.args:
  interval = solveset(interval, domain=S.Reals)
  solution &= interval
```

As you can see, we start by creating the infinite interval, and then we iterate through `intervals.args` (which are each of the inequalities previously obtained with `solve()`), to resolve the inequalities posed by each of them, and so on. have intervals whose intersection with `solution` we compute with the `&=` operator.

The result in `solution` is an interval, namely `(5, 7)` in this case, which you can already plot with the above solution.

**Note:** This solution is not quite general, depending on the input inequality it may be that in the end you will not be able to obtain a single interval-solution, but two if `solve()` generates two disjoint inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

This chained inequality should be rewritten as `ineq = And(19 < -25*x - 1, -25*x - 1 <= 37)`. It can then be re-written as an interval using `interval = ineq.as_set() -> Interval.Ropen(-38/25, -4/5)`.